# HTML5 Top horizontal menu with permanent submenu

Tags: html, css

sorry if this is really basic, but I searched for a while and couldnt find anything like it...

I would like to create a horizontal top navigation menu in html5 with a permanent horizontal submenu, which only changes when another main menu link is clicked. No dropdown etc please

Should be really simple, no?

Here I made an example: https://s12.directupload.net/images/210206/knqcngnc.png

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
.title {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 3em;
}
 #menu-container {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
 }
.menu {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.submenu {
   font-size: 1em;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<header>
<nav>
  <div>
  <span class="title">Title</span>
  </div>
  <div id="menu-container">
  <span class="menu">Menu1</span>
  <span class="submenu">SubMenu1</span>
  <span class="submenu">SubMenu2</span>
  </div>
   <div id="menu-container">
  <span class="menu">Menu2</span>
  <span class="submenu">SubMenu3</span>
  <span class="submenu">SubMenu4</span>
  </div>
</nav></header>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it truely seems easy. Some of your code is incomplete though, I tried to fix it as good as i can and let it run on https://jsfiddle.net/ but I couldn't make it work properly. Can you please look over it again?

Comment: Sorry, the code was not pasted correctly. Check it now, it is very basic